# How can I test my html code part by part automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have a long HTML file with a lot of functionalities to show and hide it.
For example, users can hide the logo, show a large title, show some blocks and all these cases can be used by various pairs.

I can have lots of these cases. I need something to test all cases (show or hide some blocks, combine some of them, etc.) without commenting on parts of my code.

By the way, the structure of the code can be changed after some variations, that's what I am trying to test.

[image]

AS it is shown in this picture, in one case it can have logo, address, contact info, and in another case it can be blank.

How can i test my web

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You'll want to make an attempt and  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you want to test your HTML tags, you can use this [tool by W3C][1]. However, if you want to test your web functionalities, you can use Cypress.

Cypress is an package of npm to test websides with tests end to end. It's based in Jquery and it's very easy to learn and use if you have basic knowledge of Javascript. You can learn how to install and use it in this [minitutorial][2] or in the [documentation][3]

I hope this tools will be useful!


 [1]: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options
 [2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drzcQ3Tt1hU
 [3]: https://www.cypress.io/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will read about it

Comment: @R_M if this comment use to solve your problem, please check it like the correct answer.

Comment: I can't check it as a correct answer because it is a comment, :(

Comment: ouch! I tried to improve your question in the post. If it is passed, i will answer with this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways you could acomplish that.
I'm using jQuery because it's on your question's tags, but you can do this with vanilla js as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-logo').click(function() {
    $('.logo').toggle()
  })
  
  $('.toggle-title').click(function() {
    $('.title').toggleClass('transparent')
  })
  
  $('.toggle-text').click(function() {
    $('.text').fadeToggle()
  })
  
  $('.toggle-section').click(function() {
    $('.section').slideToggle()
  })
})
```

```css
.transparent {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="logo"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/60x40/cccccc/000000?text=Logo" alt="My logo"></h1>

<h2 class="title">My heading</h2>

<p class="text">My site text</p>

<div class="section">
  <p>Section</p>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-logo">Toggle logo (remove space)</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-title">Toggle title (keep space)</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-text">Toggle text (fade and remove space)</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-section">Toggle section (slide and remove space)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you wanted to post this answer in your question. Please, revalue your question and i will answer you with some tools to test your web.

Comment: Thanks,
I'm trying to find some tool that would do it without writing my own js.

Comment: Yes but i can not send an answer if you do not change the question of your post.

Comment: @MCobo If it's a comment about the question, please do so on the question section, not on the answer.

Comment: @R_M I see, then disgard my answer ! For a quick prototype, I would probably just do this with Vuejs for better management.

Answer (score -1):

there is html validator but to hear you it is sort of dynamic code so won't be so helpful, i think the only way is to try it yourself, or put it in production mode and let people reporting you the problems they find while using it... (beta page)

Comment: Let's think I have 500 random variations of that blocks to show. I can't test all of them manually. :(

Comment: Surely the structure doesn't change massively between those 500 blocks, though? Only the content.

Comment: The structure is changing for example in one case I can have a logo at the top of the page and in another case, it can be placed in the bottom part, so how can I test if my HTML will look good after I placed the logo at the bottom.